# Strange iPhone crash log

Tags: iphone, crash-reports

Can anybody tell me the reason for this crash.

Specially I am concerned about this -

```
**Application Specific Information:
iMixtapes[1185] has active assertions beyond permitted time: 
{(
    <SBProcessAssertion: 0x66bc490> identifier: UIKitBackgroundCompletionTask process: iMixtapes[1185] permittedBackgroundDuration: 600.000000 reason: finishTask owner pid:1185 preventSuspend  preventIdleSleep ,
    <SBProcessAssertion: 0x66ade50> identifier: UIKitBackgroundCompletionTask process: iMixtapes[1185] permittedBackgroundDuration: 600.000000 reason: finishTask owner pid:1185 preventSuspend  preventIdleSleep 
)}
Elapsed total CPU time (seconds): 106.580 (user 62.160, system 44.420), -3% CPU 
Elapsed application CPU time (seconds): 1.700, 0% CPU**
```

Here is the crash log:

```
Incident Identifier: C5DFDDE4-2AE0-461A-937A-C422353102CE
CrashReporter Key:   3a88f20a9e18f468445bddc212b7aa673c6dc89b
Hardware Model:      iPod4,1
Process:         iMixtapes [1185]
Path:            /var/mobile/Applications/104BD0F8-BC33-43A9-AB9F-FC609750C4B6/iMixtapes.app/iMixtapes
Identifier:      iMixtapes
Version:         ??? (???)
Code Type:       ARM (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [1]

Date/Time:       2011-02-15 14:19:29.967 +0530
OS Version:      iPhone OS 4.2.1 (8C148)
Report Version:  104

Exception Type:  00000020
Exception Codes: 0x8badf00d
Highlighted Thread:  6

Application Specific Information:
iMixtapes[1185] has active assertions beyond permitted time: 
{(
    <SBProcessAssertion: 0x66bc490> identifier: UIKitBackgroundCompletionTask process: iMixtapes[1185] permittedBackgroundDuration: 600.000000 reason: finishTask owner pid:1185 preventSuspend  preventIdleSleep ,
    <SBProcessAssertion: 0x66ade50> identifier: UIKitBackgroundCompletionTask process: iMixtapes[1185] permittedBackgroundDuration: 600.000000 reason: finishTask owner pid:1185 preventSuspend  preventIdleSleep 
)}

Elapsed total CPU time (seconds): 106.580 (user 62.160, system 44.420), -3% CPU 
Elapsed application CPU time (seconds): 1.700, 0% CPU

Thread 0:
0   libSystem.B.dylib                 0x31093268 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libSystem.B.dylib                 0x31095354 mach_msg + 44
2   CoreFoundation                    0x30416648 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 88
3   CoreFoundation                    0x30415ed2 __CFRunLoopRun + 350
4   CoreFoundation                    0x30415c80 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 224
5   CoreFoundation                    0x30415b88 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 52
6   GraphicsServices                  0x31eec4a4 GSEventRunModal + 108
7   GraphicsServices                  0x31eec550 GSEventRun + 56
8   UIKit                             0x313cf322 -[UIApplication _run] + 406
9   UIKit                             0x313cce8c UIApplicationMain + 664
10  iMixtapes                         0x00002968 0x1000 + 6504
11  iMixtapes                         0x0000291c 0x1000 + 6428

Thread 1:
0   libSystem.B.dylib                 0x310bf974 kevent + 24
1   libSystem.B.dylib                 0x31169704 _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 88
2   libSystem.B.dylib                 0x31169174 _dispatch_queue_invoke + 96
3   libSystem.B.dylib                 0x31168b98 _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 120
4   libSystem.B.dylib                 0x3110d24a _pthread_wqthread + 258
5   libSystem.B.dylib                 0x31105970 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 2:
0   libSystem.B.dylib                 0x31093268 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libSystem.B.dylib                 0x31095354 mach_msg + 44
2   CoreFoundation                    0x30416648 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 88
3   CoreFoundation                    0x30415ed2 __CFRunLoopRun + 350
4   CoreFoundation                    0x30415c80 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 224
5   CoreFoundation                    0x30415b88 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 52
6   WebCore                           0x35b32124 RunWebThread(void*) + 332
7   libSystem.B.dylib                 0x3110c886 _pthread_start + 242
8   libSystem.B.dylib                 0x31101a88 thread_start + 0

Thread 3:
0   libSystem.B.dylib                 0x31093268 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libSystem.B.dylib                 0x31095354 mach_msg + 44
2   CoreFoundation                    0x30416648 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 88
3   CoreFoundation                    0x30415ed2 __CFRunLoopRun + 350
4   CoreFoundation                    0x30415c80 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 224
5   CoreFoundation                    0x30415b88 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 52
6   Foundation                        0x302fb5f6 +[NSURLConnection(NSURLConnectionReallyInternal) _resourceLoadLoop:] + 206
7   Foundation                        0x302d9192 -[NSThread main] + 38
8   Foundation                        0x302d2242 __NSThread__main__ + 966
9   libSystem.B.dylib                 0x3110c886 _pthread_start + 242
10  libSystem.B.dylib                 0x31101a88 thread_start + 0

Thread 4:
0   libSystem.B.dylib                 0x3110b9f0 __semwait_signal + 24
1   libSystem.B.dylib                 0x310c07ec _pthread_cond_wait + 748
2   libSystem.B.dylib                 0x310c03d2 pthread_cond_wait + 26
3   CoreMedia                         0x3290cb14 WaitOnCondition + 4
4   CoreMedia                         0x3290ca5a FigSemaphoreWaitRelative + 66
5   MediaToolbox                      0x32a8bc9c fpa_AsyncMovieControlThread + 48
6   CoreMedia                         0x32928f76 figThreadMain + 166
7   libSystem.B.dylib                 0x3110c886 _pthread_start + 242
8   libSystem.B.dylib                 0x31101a88 thread_start + 0

Thread 5:
0   libSystem.B.dylib                 0x310b768c select$DARWIN_EXTSN + 20
1   CoreFoundation                    0x3044d662 __CFSocketManager + 582
2   libSystem.B.dylib                 0x3110c886 _pthread_start + 242
3   libSystem.B.dylib                 0x31101a88 thread_start + 0

Thread 6:
0   libSystem.B.dylib                 0x3110b9f0 __semwait_signal + 24
1   libSystem.B.dylib                 0x310c07ec _pthread_cond_wait + 748
2   libSystem.B.dylib                 0x310c03d2 pthread_cond_wait + 26
3   iMixtapes                         0x000945b0 0x1000 + 603568
4   iMixtapes                         0x000953ec 0x1000 + 607212
5   iMixtapes                         0x0008f3a6 0x1000 + 582566
6   AudioToolbox                      0x3281e376 AudioFileStreamWrapper::CallPacketsProc(unsigned long, unsigned long, void const*, AudioStreamPacketDescription*, bool) + 122
7   AudioToolbox                      0x3283adfa MP3AudioStream::GeneratePackets(AudioFileStreamContinuation&) + 2226
8   AudioToolbox                      0x3281e5e4 AudioFileStreamWrapper::ParseBytes(unsigned long, void const*, unsigned long) + 180
9   AudioToolbox                      0x3281de6c AudioFileStreamParseBytes + 132
10  iMixtapes                         0x00093fe6 0x1000 + 602086
11  iMixtapes                         0x0008f466 0x1000 + 582758
12  CoreFoundation                    0x3044ef6a _signalEventSync + 70
13  CoreFoundation                    0x3044f842 _cfstream_solo_signalEventSync + 58
14  CoreFoundation                    0x3044c7ee _CFStreamSignalEvent + 326
15  CoreFoundation                    0x3044c6a0 CFReadStreamSignalEvent + 4
16  CFNetwork                         0x32fe2a66 HTTPReadStream::streamEvent(unsigned long) + 94
17  CFNetwork                         0x32fe2adc HTTPReadStream::_streamCB(__CFReadStream*, unsigned long, void*) + 24
18  CoreFoundation                    0x3044ef6a _signalEventSync + 70
19  CoreFoundation                    0x3044eefe _cfstream_shared_signalEventSync + 198
20  CoreFoundation                    0x304447d6 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 6
21  CoreFoundation                    0x304165b0 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 376
22  CoreFoundation                    0x30415e54 __CFRunLoopRun + 224
23  CoreFoundation                    0x30415c80 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 224
24  CoreFoundation                    0x30415b88 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 52
25  Foundation                        0x302d28e4 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 196
26  iMixtapes                         0x00090ed8 0x1000 + 589528
27  Foundation                        0x302d9192 -[NSThread main] + 38
28  Foundation                        0x302d2242 __NSThread__main__ + 966
29  libSystem.B.dylib                 0x3110c886 _pthread_start + 242
30  libSystem.B.dylib                 0x31101a88 thread_start + 0

Thread 7:
0   libSystem.B.dylib                 0x31093268 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libSystem.B.dylib                 0x31095354 mach_msg + 44
2   CoreFoundation                    0x30416648 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 88
3   CoreFoundation                    0x30415ed2 __CFRunLoopRun + 350
4   CoreFoundation                    0x30415c80 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 224
5   CoreFoundation                    0x30415b88 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 52
6   AudioToolbox                      0x327a84ba GenericRunLoopThread::RunLoop() + 30
7   AudioToolbox                      0x327bb306 TRunLoop<AQClient>::Entry(void*) + 90
8   AudioToolbox                      0x327a81d2 CAPThread::Entry(CAPThread*) + 138
9   libSystem.B.dylib                 0x3110c886 _pthread_start + 242
10  libSystem.B.dylib                 0x31101a88 thread_start + 0

Unknown thread crashed with unknown flavor: 5, state_count: 1
```

Comment: Ugh, and you want us to parse this unformatted mess ? Please take your time and format your question, especially if it's such a huge dump.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4726254/uikitbackgroundcompletiontask-iphone-application-crash) for the same error. The answer there is:

> This means that EVERY background task created with `beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:` call MUST be ended `withendBackgroundTask:`. Double check that `endBackgroundTask:` is invoked with the correct task id.

Comment: Know of an easy way to do this without capturing the task id in a property or static variable?