# iphone - how much time can an app in "Sleep" state

Tags: objective-c, background, sleep

Helo guys,

Im having a strange issue.
My app works in the background endlessly because it's a location app(yes location based apps can run endlessly).

The thing is that "sometimes" after some time (amounts like 5, 10 or 36 hours) it crashes while it's in the background, with the following message:

```
identifier: UIKitBackgroundCompletionTask process: MyApp[7149] permittedBackgroundDuration: 600.000000 reason: finishTask owner pid:7149 preventSuspend  preventIdleSleep
```

I've been checking for this and I can't find a straight answer. Since it doesnt crash after those 10 mins, but "whenever it feels like" Im thinking it could be related to the way I make sleep the app.
If I press home, it goes to the background, but If i press "Sleep/wake" button it's on another state, sleeping mode, could that state make my app eventually crash after an indetermined amount of time?

Thanks.

[EDIT]
Aparently this is a similar issue to NSURLConnection crashing under 10.5.7
But since this is an iPhone app I thought it wouldnt be my issue. Also Im not using those methods to connect, maybe you can help me, these are the methods I use to connect to my webservice while in background mode:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString: @"http://mywebservice.com?wsdl"];//to create the url
[NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:req delegate:self];//sending the request

NSMutableURLRequest *req = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData timeoutInterval:30];
// and then to address the answer of the server
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response 
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
```

Comment: i would run zombies and see if there is some kind of memory issue, kinda sucks though that you may need to wait 36hours to see!

Comment: Hmm... looks to me like this is either the same or related to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5003120/strange-iphone-crash-log