# ARC memory issue with SQLitePersistence class

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory-leaks, automatic-ref-counting

I can't be able to figure out why does app crashes, while inserting the data into a database by using `SQLitePersistence` class.

After downloaded the product xml data from webservice, I'm trying to insert all the product details into the various table like,

```
Product 
Product_image
Product_option
Product_categories
Product_custom_option
```

As for now, we have 800 products available on the webservice, in future it may increase about 2000 product.

**My problem is** : after inserting 400 to 450 products, app crashes regularly. Then I use `@autorelesepool` for each and every loop of inserting the data to database. It increases 500 to 550 products then app crashes, what can I do next to avoid app crashes?

My `SQLitePersistence` database class for Product table `.h` file:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "SQLitePersistentObject.h"

@interface iMobDB : SQLitePersistentObject
{
    NSString *sku;
    NSString *name;
    .....
    .....
}
@property(nonatomic,retain) NSString *sku;
@property(nonatomic,retain) NSString *name;
.....
.....
@end
```

`.m` file

```
@implementation iMobDB

@synthesize sku;
@synthesize name;
    .....
    .....

-(void) dealloc
{
    for (NSString *one in [[self class] propertiesWithEncodedTypes])
    {
        [self removeObserver:self forKeyPath:one];
    }
    iMobReleaseNil(sku);
    iMobReleaseNil(name);
    .....
    .....
}
```

Im inserting the data here in `Appdelegate` class

```
 /*===================================== Save Product Information ===============================================*/

        iMobDB *imobdb = [[iMobDB alloc]init];
        imobdb.productId = [productid intValue];
        imobdb.sku = skukey;
        imobdb.name = namekey;
        imobdb.optionalOption = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",options];
        imobdb.requriedOption = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",requried];
        imobdb.productType = producttypekey;
        imobdb.price = pricekey;
        imobdb.specialprice = specialpricekey;
        imobdb.stock = [stock intValue];
        imobdb.manufacture = manukey;
        [imobdb save];
        imobdb=nil;

        /*==============================================================================================================*/

        /*==================================== Save Product Images =====================================================*/
       __unsafe_unretained NSDictionary  *imagearray=[[dict objectForKey:@"images"] objectForKey:@"url"];

        @autoreleasepool 
        {

        for (NSDictionary *dict in imagearray)
        {
            if ([dict  isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]])
            {
                NSString *imageurl=[dict objectForKey:@"text"];                
                ImageDB *imagedb = [[ImageDB alloc] init];
                imagedb.productId = [productid intValue];
                imagedb.imageurl = imageurl;
                [imagedb save];
                imagedb=nil;
            }
            else if([dict  isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]])
            {
                NSString *imageurl=[dict objectForKey:@"text"];              
                ImageDB *imagedb = [[ImageDB alloc] init];
                imagedb.productId = [productid intValue];
                imagedb.imageurl = imageurl;
                [imagedb save];
                imagedb=nil;
            }
        }

        }
        /*===============================================================================================================*/

        /*==================================== Save Category ============================================================*/
        @autoreleasepool 
        {

      __unsafe_unretained  NSDictionary *categorydict = [dict objectForKey:@"categories"];

                for (NSDictionary *dictt in catedict)
                {
                 __unsafe_unretained   NSString *categoryid=[[dictt objectForKey:@"categoryId"]objectForKey:@"text"];
                __unsafe_unretained    NSString *categoryname=[[dictt objectForKey:@"categoryName"]objectForKey:@"text"];                    
                    Categories *catdb  = [[Categories alloc] init];
                    catdb.categoryId = [categoryid intValue];
                    catdb.categoryname = categoryname;
                    catdb.productId = [productid intValue];
                    [catdb save];
                    catdb=nil;
                }
            }
```

Please note: I have disable the ARC in the following class

[image]

**Error log Screenshot**

[image]

**Error log**

> Feb  1 11:53:59 Innoppl-iPod backboardd[52] : iMob[2811] has
>   active assertions beyond permitted time:      {(
>          identifier: Suspending process: iMob[2811] permittedBackgroundDuration: 10.000000 reason: suspend
>   owner pid:52 preventSuspend  preventThrottleDownCPU 
>   preventThrottleDownUI     )} Feb  1 11:53:59 Innoppl-iPod backboardd[52]
>   : Forcing crash report of iMob[2811]... Feb  1 11:53:59
>   Innoppl-iPod backboardd[52] : Finished crash reporting. Feb 
>   1 11:53:59 Innoppl-iPod ReportCrash[2819] : libMobileGestalt
>   copySystemVersionDictionaryValue: Could not lookup ReleaseType from
>   system version dictionary Feb  1 11:53:59 Innoppl-iPod
>   com.apple.launchd[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OjG70.png)
>   (UIKitApplication:com.innoppl.Saletab[0xe1bf][2811]) :
>   (UIKitApplication:com.innoppl.Saletab[0xe1bf]) Exited: Killed: 9 Feb 
>   1 11:53:59 Innoppl-iPod backboardd[52] : Application
>   'UIKitApplication:com.innoppl.Saletab[0xe1bf]' exited abnormally with
>   signal 9: Killed: 9 Feb  1 11:53:59 Innoppl-iPod ReportCrash[2819]
>   : Saved crashreport to
>   /var/mobile/Library/Logs/CrashReporter/iMob_2013-02-01-115359_Innoppl-iPod.plist
>   using uid: 0 gid: 0, synthetic_euid: 501 egid: 0

Comment: Is all of this stored in-memory or on a file?

Comment: Please post the stacktrace of the crash.

Comment: @Resh32 All the data's are stored in SQLite database by using SQLitePersistence class.

Comment: @trojanfoe Above I have attached the screenshot of error log report

Comment: OK, that isn't a stacktrace, but that's because the app was killed with `SIGKILL`, which means I don't think you can get a stacktrace.  It's time to run your app through `Instruments` `leak` tool...

Comment: Are you doing that as a background process (I mean when the app is suspended)?

Comment: @Resh32 No, I'm downloading and saving the data in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions, When app launch 1st time.

Comment: the permittedBackgroundDuration  is what triggered my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5003120/strange-iphone-crash-log

Comment: Have you found the solution?

Comment: @Resh32 After upgrading my Xcode version 4.2 to 4.6 resolved app crashed but, still i'm getting memory issues,

Comment: Did you try to profile the app in memory leak mode?