# How to fix MP3AudioStream error?

Tags: ios, avplayer, audiotoolbox, background-audio

I'm getting the following error randomly (and sometimes consistently on launch).  It can happen when there are background threads and when there aren't and it seems to be a problem with the library so I'm having trouble tracking down the problem in my code.  The breakpoint triggers on:

```
#0  0x07bb489b in MP3AudioStream::GeneratePackets(AudioFileStreamContinuation&) ()
```

and the backtrace is as follows:

```
* thread #1: tid = 0x1c03, 0x07bb489b AudioToolbox`MP3AudioStream::GeneratePackets(AudioFileStreamContinuation&) + 2843, stop reason = EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x4)
frame #0: 0x07bb489b AudioToolbox`MP3AudioStream::GeneratePackets(AudioFileStreamContinuation&) + 2843
frame #1: 0x07b92535 AudioToolbox`AudioFileStreamWrapper::ParseBytes(unsigned long, void const*, unsigned long) + 181
frame #2: 0x07b8f41d AudioToolbox`AudioFileStreamParseBytes + 93
frame #3: 0x07f7a1be MediaToolbox`PushBytesThroughParser + 484
frame #4: 0x07f7a69a MediaToolbox`GetAudioFileStreamPacketAndFrameCount + 221
frame #5: 0x07f7c57e MediaToolbox`FigAudioFileStreamFormatReaderCopyProperty + 225
frame #6: 0x07f9bd1d MediaToolbox`FigPlaybackBossGetDuration + 165
frame #7: 0x07f9f75a MediaToolbox`FigPlaybackBossSetTimeWithRange + 192
frame #8: 0x07f66bef MediaToolbox`itemfig_rebuildRenderPipelinesAndBoss + 10196
frame #9: 0x07f63f01 MediaToolbox`playerfig_prepareWorkingItem2 + 117
frame #10: 0x07f5bdb9 MediaToolbox`playerfig_prepareWorkingItem + 88
frame #11: 0x07f6c536 MediaToolbox`itemfig_assetPropertyBatchLoaded_prepareWorkingItem + 125
frame #12: 0x01bc8758 CoreMedia`figDeferredNotificationRun + 69
frame #13: 0x01de4376 CoreFoundation`__CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_TIMER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 22
frame #14: 0x01de3e06 CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopDoTimer + 534
frame #15: 0x01dcba82 CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopRun + 1810
frame #16: 0x01dcaf44 CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 276
frame #17: 0x01dcae1b CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
frame #18: 0x02afb7e3 GraphicsServices`GSEventRunModal + 88
frame #19: 0x02afb668 GraphicsServices`GSEventRun + 104
frame #20: 0x00330ffc UIKit`UIApplicationMain + 1211
frame #21: 0x00002a7d FMA`main(argc=1, argv=0xbffff3f0) + 141 at main.m:16
```

Has anyone had this error and does anyone know how I might go about fixing it?

Comment: Are you trying to play/download music when the app is in bg ?

Comment: I have it set up to do that, but I'm getting this error when the app is in the foreground and has not been backgrounded.

Comment: I saw in other SO post that this crash log can be caused by the beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler, I don't know if is your case too but if it is you should check http://stackoverflow.com/a/5003199/2315974

Comment: It isn't.  I'm not using `beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler` anywhere in my code.